# Stack Overflow vs Super Users in terms of the community

Tags: discussion, support

after a few complications I have decided to spend more time on Super User, instead of Stack Overflow.

Just a question, how different is stack overflow from super user in terms of what technology the two communities generally use? I mean, do super users use netbeam, rather than eclipse and VS?

I would like to know this so I know what questions I should and should not post on Super User; I'm not going to post a VS question if most of the users don't know what VS is.

thanks guys

Comment: Super User does not focus on programming, but more on software and hardware for personal and home computing. It's not a *substitute* for Stack Overflow, it's a completely different site with an entirely different scope.

Comment: Thanks, that was my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking, questions about using programming tools such as IDEs should go on Stack Overflow. Super User is more about consumer-type applications and operating systems.

As [animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/141525/animuson) said in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146328/stack-overflow-vs-super-users-in-terms-of-the-community#comment418927_146328),

> Super User does not focus on programming, but more on software and hardware for personal and home computing. It's not a substitute for Stack Overflow, it's a completely different site with an entirely different scope.

You can also refer to the FAQs (see below).

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
>
> ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

vs [Super User](https://superuser.com/faq):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is not about ...
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
>
> ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!